# Binding to DependencyProperty doesnt work

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have 2 views (first view - custom user control, MainWindow view - main view with first custom control as a child).

First view has TreeView and **DependencyProperty SelectedModel** which changes when user change selection in TreeView.
Main window view also has label with binding to SelectedModel property of MainWindowModel.

Label doesnt updates.

Comment: pls use edit to add your code to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by setting the `DataContext` of your `FirstView`, it breaks the data inheritance so your `FirstView` won't have access to the data (i.e. `SelectedModel`) defined in your main viewmodel.

Try commenting out

```
public FirstView() 
{ 
    InitializeComponent(); 
    //this.DataContext = _viewModel;  
}
```

and see if it works.

Comment: I comment "this.DataContext = _viewModel;", remove FirstViewModel and add additional DependencyProperty VendorsSourceProperty to FirstView. I also set <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VendorsSource}">. And now tree view doesn load any items :(

Comment: VendorsSource should just be a collection of vendors and should be set in your main view model. It doesn't need to be a dependency property.

Comment: I place ObservableCollection<VendorModel> Vendors to MainWindowViewModel and edit MainWindowView to <views:VendorView SelectedModel="{Binding Path=SelectedModel}"
                          VendorsSource="{Binding Path=Vendors}"/>. In VendorView I add DependencyProperty VendorsSourceProperty and set <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VendorsSource}">. How can I bind treeview in VendorView to collection in MainWindowViewModel without VendorsSourceProperty?

Comment: If I set <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Vendors}"/> it's will load items, but why child view must known collection name of parent view?

Comment: I got you now... What is the type of VendorsSourceProperty?

Comment: public static readonly DependencyProperty VendorsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("VendorsSource", typeof(ObservableCollection<Model.VendorModel>), typeof(VendorView));

Comment: I also try <TreeView SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=VendorsSource}"/> but it doesnt solve problem too. In debugger I see that ObservableCollection<VendorModel> Vendors property in MainWindowViewModel is requsted but setter of ObservableCollection<Model.VendorModel> VendorsSource in VendorView never calls.

Comment: Hi, I think you are missing just one thing. You should name your FirstView usercontrol (e.g. 'MyFirstView') and bind ItemsSource of your TreeView using ElementName binding, something like this, ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VendorsSource, ElementName=MyFirstView}">

Comment: No-no. VendorsSource is a property of FirstView. VendorsView is a view with treeview control for showing items collection defined in main window view.

Comment: I am confused. In your code, you defined VendorsSource in your VendorsView... So there are three views?

Comment: TreeView is a part of VendorsView.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9569/discussion-between-xin-and-dmitriy)